# How to get information about a chat bot in aiogram 3.0

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

I need to check the bot for administrator rights

The library has the get_chat_member method. However, when I try to call it and pass the parameters of the ID chat and the user, I get the error 'module' object is not callable. I have no way to call get_chat_member from an object of the Bot class, because it is declared in another file and there is no way to import it, and get_chat_member from aiogram.methods gives the above error